# Перегрузка оператора + для класса комплексных чисел (Builder C++)

Tags: c++, классы, c++builder

Вообщем, нужно перегрузить оператор + для класса комплексных чисел, вроде-бы как сделал, в dev c++ заработало, перенёс в c++builder, перестало нормально работать.
Вот что происходит при нажатии кнопки: выводит в 1 поле(действительная часть) - 0 и в 2 поле(мнимая часть) - 2,3693...

Сам класс:

```
class Complex
{
    private:
        float real;
        float imagine;


public:

    Complex()
{
    real = 0;
    imagine = 0;
}

    Complex(float a, float b)
{
    real = a;
    imagine = b;
}

    Complex(const Complex &)
    {}



    friend Complex operator +(const Complex &left, const Complex &right)
    {
            Complex temp;
            temp.real=left.real + right.real;
            temp.imagine=left.imagine + right.imagine;
            return temp;
    }

    float getReal()
    {
            return real;
    }

    float getImagine()
    {
            return imagine;
    }
```

Кнопка:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{

    C_Complex = A_Complex + B_Complex;

    Edit6->Text=FloatToStr(C_Complex.getReal());
    Edit7->Text=FloatToStr(C_Complex.getImagine());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы в своем коде зачем-то умышленно подавили функциональность конструктора копирования. Поэтому ничего и не работает. Поведение такого кода будет зависеть от успешности оптимизаций RVO, т.е. от того, будет ли фактически использоваться компилятором этот "убитый" конструктор копирования.

Answer (score 0):

Вышел из этой ситуации написав перегрузку немного по-другому, но все равно, хотелось бы узнать, почему в примере выше программа не работает правильно.

```
Complex operator+(const Complex &a)
{
    return Complex(this->real + a.real, this->imagine+a.imagine);
}
```

Comment: Это бессмысленное исправление, которое ничего не исправляет. Зачем вы умышленно "подавили" конструктор копирования? Потому ничего и не работает.